# Sudden receive-buffer buildup on CentOS for C++ application

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, centos, udp

I have a somewhat strange problem when receiving UDP data on CentOS. When my application receives data everything is fine at first and all packets are received as expected, then all of a sudden the kernel receive buffer (net.core.rmem) starts to fill up for no apparent reason until it's full and packets are dropped. The strange part is that the buffer is more or less empty until all of a sudden when it starts to increase dramatically even though the sending party sends at the same rate as before. As if a resource I haven't accounted for is depleted, or the operating system changes priority of the thread dedicated for receive operations. Data is still received and read by `receive()`, but the buffer starts to fill too fast.

Files are sent from the sending application to the receiving application. There is a unidirectional gateway between the sending and receiving application, so there is no possibility for congestion control (or TCP) what so ever. The problem only arises when I send a big file (around 3 GiB or more). Everything works fine when I send multiple small files, even if the sum of their size is much larger than 3 GiB.

At the moment I'm unable to specify the problem further and I'm pretty stunned as to what could be wrong. This is the information about the systems configuration that I can imagine being relevant, but I've looked into memory leaks, disk usage and buffer sizes without being able to find something specific.

- Data is sent at a rate of 100 Mbit/s.
- MTU is 9000 on both the sending and receiving machine.
- `net.core.rmem_max`/`net.core.rmem_default` is set to `536870912` Bytes (huge).
- `net.core.netdev_max_backlog` is set to `65536` (huge).
- Each UDP packet sent is 8192 Bytes, excluding the UDP header.
- A temporary file created through `tmpfile()` is used to store the data for each file.
- The temporary file is closed as soon as the file is completed (hashsum is verified).
- CPU usage when receiving files is consistent at 100%.
- Memory usage when receiving files is consistent at 0.5%.

---

**receive()**

```
std::vector<uint8_t>* vector = new std::vector<uint8_t>();

while (signal == 0)
{
  ret = _serverio->Receive(*vector);
  if (ret == -1 || ret == 0)
  {
    continue;
  }
  else
  {
    Produce(vector);
    vector = new std::vector<uint8_t>();
  }
}
```

**_serverio->Receive(std::vector& data)**

```
ssize_t n;
data.resize(UDPMAXMSG);
int res = m_fdwait.Wait(m_timeoutms);
if(res < 1) {
  data.resize(0);
  return res; // timeout or interrupt
}

n = read(m_servfd, &(data[0]), data.size());
if(n < 0) {
  if(errno == EINTR) {
    data.resize(0);
    return -1;
  }
  else {
    throw socket_error(errno, "UDPServer::Receive");
  }
}
data.resize(n);
return n;
```

**Produce(std::vector* vector)**

```
_producerSemaphore.aquire();
_queue.lock();
_buffer.push_back(vector);
_queue.unlock();
_consumerSemaphore.release();
```

**Consume()**

```
bool aquired = false;
while (!aquired)
{
  if (_terminated)
  {
    // Consume should return NULL immediately if
    // receiver has been terminated.
    return NULL;
  }

  aquired = _consumerSemaphore.aquire_timeout(1);
}

std::vector<uint8_t>* vector = NULL;
_queue.lock();
vector = _buffer.front();
_buffer.pop_front();
_queue.unlock();
_producerSemaphore.release();

return vector;
```

**recv_buffer.sh (for monitoring of the receive buffer)**

```
while true ; do
  _BUFFER_VALUE=$(printf "%d" "0x$(grep 2710 /proc/net/udp \
    | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/.*://')")
  _DELTA=$(expr $_BUFFER_VALUE - $_PRE_BUFFER)
  _PRE_BUFFER=$_BUFFER_VALUE
  echo "$_BUFFER_VALUE : $_DELTA"
  sleep 0.1
done
```

---

**recv_buffer.sh output**

```
buffer-size delta
0 0
0 0
...
10792 10792
10792 0
0 -10792
10792 10792
0 -10792
0 0
0 0
0 0 // This type of pattern goes on for 2.5 GiB
...
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
971280 971280 // At this point the buffer starts to fill
1823848 852568
1931768 107920
2039688 107920
2179984 140296
2287904 107920
2406616 118712
2525328 118712
2644040 118712
2741168 97128
2881464 140296
3010968 129504
3140472 129504
...
533567272 647520
536038640 2471368
536675368 636728
536880416 205048 // At this point packets are dropped
536869624 -10792
536880416 10792
536880416 0
536869624 -10792
536880416 10792
536869624 -10792
536880416 10792
536880416 0
536880416 0
536880416 0
536880416 0
536880416 0
```

Comment: "CPU usage when receiving files is consistent at 100%." - don't do busy wait.

Comment: I don't do busy wait. The receiving thread (running `receive()`) blocks while waiting for I/O as seen in `_serverio->Receive(std::vector& data)`. The processing threads blocks while waiting for a buffer to consume as seen in `Consume()`. Both functions periodically (once every second) checks if the application is terminated. The CPU is at 100% only when a large amount of data is being received.

Comment: Do you have a CPU bottleneck at high data rates? Well, that's a problem, and then I'm not sure what your question is...

Comment: Well, I guess you're right in that I do have a bottleneck at high data rates, but I would assume this would present itself as a gradual buildup of data in the receive buffer (and gradual buildup of memory requires to hold unprocessed buffers). But I wouldn't expect it to go from processing everything on time to suddenly choking.

Comment: @JakobPogulis Could there be some sort of threading deadlock?